# Muon decay - Type of interaction

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, leptons

Why does weak interaction occur when a muon decays?
Why can't electromagnetic interaction occur when a muon decays?

Answer (score 0):

Because muon number and electron number are conserved:

$$ \mu^- \rightarrow e^- + \gamma $$

violates those conservation laws.

Comment: Neutrino mixing violates lepton flavour conservation. $\mu \to e \gamma$ is allowed but extremely suppressed.